# Добавить массив в Control

Tags: c#, wpf

Создала UserControl, с использованием библиотеки MahApps.Metro

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="shopItems"
                   Height="auto">
            <mah:Tile Style="{StaticResource SmallTileStyle}" />
        </WrapPanel>
```

В стилях контрола есть объекты, в которые я помещаю отдельный текст из массива

```
<TextBlock x:Name="itemName"
                                   Margin="10,131,0,33"
                                   FontSize="16"
                                   Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                                   Text="{Binding Title}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Но при запуске контрола отображается только один элемент, а не масса из списка

```
shopItems.DataContext = list;
```

Как мне отображать список этого элемента?

```
<mah:Tile Style="{StaticResource SmallTileStyle}" />
```

Comment: http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/11/f18423a10e359363fc28d433eefa583c.png      отображается один блок,  а массив может содержать множество элементов, которые нужно прикрутить.    Так я загружаю список объектов  `    tileItems.DataContext = list;`   tileItems - имя объекта  <mah:Tile...

Answer (score 1):

Решила таким образом

```
public ObservableCollection<ShopItem> Elements { get; set; }
```

И через цикл прогнала весь список объектов